# Symfony2 Form Collection of entities with one-to-one relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony-forms

have You met with a situation in which the form contains a collection of entities that includes a one-to-one relation?

I have entity that has many addresses and every address has one-to-one relation to other entity. I have problem when displaying saved data because when I use

```
{% for address in form.clubAddress %}
<div class="entry grid_9">
    <div class="grid_12">
        {{ form_widget(address.street) }}
        {{ form_widget(address.geoInfo.street) }}
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

it display only last geoInfo element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone would be intrested the problem was with

```
form_widget()
```

each one-to-one element had identical id, so form_widget was displayed only once. I made a macro to workaround this problem.